# Elastic search : query not searching numeric value

Tags: elasticsearch

I have one field in which I am storing values like O5467508 (Starting with alphabet "O")

Below is my query.

```
{"from":0,"size":10,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"field_LIST_105":{"query":"o5467508","type":"phrase_prefix"}}},{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"RegionName":"Virginia"}}]}}]}}}
```

it is giving me correct result, But when i am searching for only numeric value "5467508", query result is empty.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible solution that could help you, use `word_delimiter` filter, with the option `preserve_original`, which will save original token.

Something like this:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "so_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "my_word_delimiter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "my_word_delimiter": {
          "type": "word_delimiter",
          "preserve_original": true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "field_LIST_105": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "so_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I did a quick test of analysis, and this is the tokens that it give to me.

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "o5467508",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 8,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "o",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 1,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "5467508",
            "start_offset": 1,
            "end_offset": 8,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

For more information - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html